# C++ map returning different values

Tags: c++

I am writing a program, and I could swear that the Map is returning different values than I put in.  I don't actually believe that this is the case, but that I'm missing something that I should do when using maps.

`choices` is a `std::map<int,Board>`, `choice` and `board` is a `Board`, and `getId()` will return a unique int hash.

Here's a portion of my generation code (when I am building up my map):

```
if (choices.find(board.getId())!=choices.end())//If choices already contains the new state
    std::cout<<"Error!"<<std::endl;
checkGoodMove(board,choice);
choices.insert(std::pair<int,Board>(board.getId(),choice));
```

Then, this is the code when I access my map:

```
if (choices.find(board.getId())==choices.end())
    std::cout<<"Error!"<<std::endl;
 auto choice = choices[board.getId()];
 checkGoodMove(board, choice);
 return choice;
```

Here's what's happening:

1. I build my entire map at once.  The only insert function is the one you see.
2. When I build my map, I verify that `board.getID()` returns a unique value because "Error" is never printed out.
3. I also verify that my map contains the ID before I access it because, once again, "Error" is never printed.
4. `checkGoodMove`  verifies that the move from the first state and the second state is a valid move.  It *never* throws an error when building my map, but will frequently throw an error when accessing.

Why am I getting random states back from the map, when I am putting in perfectly valid states in?

Comment: You are probably trying to read a non-existing board id from the map. The behavior of `operator[]` in this case is to insert a default constructed Board and return it. Try using `find` instead,

Comment: `auto choice = choices[board.getId()];` can add items to the map if the key doesn't exist already.  You might consider using `find` there as well.

Comment: I have verified that the ID is already in the map before I access it.  Adding it to the description.

Comment: Well, the values are being added somehow, and if those are the only two places you access the map it's one of those.  Time for the debugger.

Comment: Could you post a [minimal complete example](http://sscce.org)? It would save a lot of guesswork.

Comment: Beta...there's quite a bit of code in the generation, and so it would not be minimal at all.  I have included what I feel is relevant, but if you want other specific items, I can definitely post them.

Comment: Your problem doesn't seems to be on the posted code. As Beta said, the ideal would be if you could exclude all irrelevant parts and still leave a **compilable** program that shows the unexpected behavior. This way you will be sure the problem is in there.

Comment: Ok...I will see what I can do, thanks.

Comment: You need to boil it down to an [sscce](http://sscce.org/). Doing so will either (a) help you solve it, (b) provide someone here the information they need to solve it for you. The problem will be that you're storing a "Board" in your map, but we don't see either the definition of Board, it's copy constructors, or the definition of your map. All kinda crucial to helping you solve this, and none of them supplied.

Comment: Are you sure that `getId()` is a deterministic function?

Comment: @kfsone, that's because I didn't create `Board`.  I do have a high guarantee, however, that it is properly created, and that `getId()` works properly.  My map definition is trivial: `std::map<int, Board>`

Comment: What is `checkGoodMove` testing and why is it failing? Does `Board` have an explicit copy/move constructor that might not be copying the object properly?

Comment: `checkGoodMove` basically tests that the movement from the first board to the second is a valid move.  Its specific to Board, so I didn't include it.  No, it does not have a copy/move constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code provided and the OPs assertions of correctness, the problem must be in the copy or assignment operator of Board. Note that 'auto choice' will make choice a copy of the right hand side. It seems strange that you don't use a const reference

```
const auto& choice = choices[board.getId()];
```

And take the argument the same way in checkGoodMove.

Alternatively, the code in checkGoodMove is at fault.